# How does SharePoint versioning engine store only changes to files and not the whole file?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, file-storage

One of the many things that SharePoint does extremely well is that when you have versioning enabled for files uploaded to a Document Library, every time you save changes to a file it only saves the difference from the previous version of the file to the Content Database but NOT the whole file again.

I am trying to duplicate that same behavior with standard C# code on either a File System folder in Windows or a SQL Database blob field. Does anyone have any idea or pointers on how SharePoint accomplishes this and how it can be done outside of SharePoint?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint uses a technique called data "shredding" to contain each change to a given file.  Unfortunately, I don't think you will find enough technical details to truly reproduce what they are doing, but you might be able to devise a reasonable approximation using your own design.

When shredded, the data associated with a file such as Document.docx is distributed across a set of BLOBs associated with the file. The independent BLOBS are each assigned a unique ID (offset) to enable reconstruction in the correct order when requested by a user.

Each document "shred" is stored in a SQL database table named DocStreams. Each BLOB contains a numerical Id representative of the source BLOB when coalesced. When a client updates a file, only the shredded BLOB that corresponds to the change is updated with the update occurring on the database server as opposed to the Web server.

For more details on Shredding see

- http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/6/6/9661DAC2-393D-445A-BDC1-E60743B1231E/Shredded%20Storage%20in%20SharePoint%202013.pdf
- https://jeremythake.com/the-truth-behind-shredded-storage-in-sharepoint-2013-a84ec047f28e
- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/91b369/shredded-storage-in-sharepoint-2013/